# is there any mistake I have done>?

Tags: php, sql

I write this php code to get the variable from my contact form, mail them and insert them into the database. Everything is working well but it doesn't insert into my database

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //catch errors
    ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
    //GET THE PASSING VARIABELS
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['message']);
    $IP = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['IP']);
    $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['country']);
    $countrycode = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['countrycode']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['city']);
    //INSERTING INTO DATABASE
    $mysqli = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, message, IP, city, country, countrycode) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$message', '$IP', '$city', '$country', '$countrycode')";  
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, $mysqli);
    //mail the data
    $mailTo = "Adminmohammad@menuelist.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$email;
    $txt = "You have recieved an e-mail from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

    mail($mailTo, $headers, $txt);
    if($query){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('شكرا لتواصلكم سيتم الرد عليكم بأقرب وقت ممكن')</script>";
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('../contact.php?IP=".$IP."&country=".$country."&countrycode=".$countrycode."&city=".$city."&mail=".success."');</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('حدث خطأ ما والرجاء المحاولة في ما بعد')</script>";
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('../index.php?inserting = error');</script>";
    }
}else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('الرجاء ملئ البيانات المطلوبة')</script>";
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('../index.php?submitting = failed');</script>";    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you have to clean up the code a little bit first and then add some debugging to figure out what is happening:

1. Place the ini_set and error_reporting to the beginning of the file
2. Clean up the passing of the variables
3. `sign('../index.php?submitting = failed');` -> remove the spaces around the `=`
4. Get the sql query and run it directly on the database to see if the query works (`var_dump($mysqli);`)
5. See if the result is true (`var_dump($query);`)
6. See if you actually have access to the `$connection` object (mysqli object).

```
    <?php
    //catch errors
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include_once 'db.php';
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        //GET THE PASSING VARIABELS
        foreach (array('name', 'email','message','IP','country','countrycode','city')as$key)
            ${$key} = $_POST[$key];

        //INSERTING INTO DATABASE
        $mysqli = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, message, IP, city, country, countrycode) 
                    VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$message', '$IP', '$city', '$country', '$countrycode')";
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, $mysqli);


        var_dump($mysqli); // the sql query that is executed -> should run on db
        var_dump($query); // result -> should be true
        var_dump($connection); // should be a mysqli object

    }
```

I cannot see in your db.php but i think the problem lays there. If you do not have a mysqli object in `$connection` you should try to add `global $connection` to the beginning of the file to get in in the variable scope. More information: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Second thing you could do to get a proper error:

```
   try {
       //INSERTING INTO DATABASE
   } catch (Exception $e) {
       echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }
```

Comment: thank you for your notices, I put this in my codeand it show up a long error message all I understand that there is a duplicate entry(0) for PRIMARY key ID I empty tha table contact and it worked then i tried again and its failed

Comment: thank you again for your tips it helps a lot ,and the problem was tha ID column doesnt A.I